# loop getting a query from a list + pages

Tags: python, selenium, loops

I'm trying to make a loop getting a query from a list I've read from an xlsx file, inside a loop that turns the page each time.

But it gives me this error:

```
You can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook('test2.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
queries = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]

n_pages=5

for query in queries:
  for page in range(1, n_pages):
   url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + \
    query + "&start=" + str((page - 1) * 10)
  driver.get(url)
```

I know it's wrong, but I don't know how to add the query to it and at the same time increase the value of the page.

Comment: What values are in your cells? Can you show us and example of the urls that you want to generate?

Comment: Yes, for example something like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:amazon.com+intext:%22TV%22&ei=CDZZY6e4IOeGur4PtLuYaA&start=20&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwin3O6FgP76AhVng84BHbQdBg04ChDy0wN6BAgBEAc&biw=1366&bih=592&dpr=1
what is this query:  ` site:amazon.com intext:"TV" `

With a single query I can do it, but not with a list.

Comment: So you want to join all of the cells into a single string? You can do something like `' '.join(values)`.